# Xcode 7 where is Localization Locking?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

In previous version of Xcode it was there in Interface Builder document:

[image]

But not in Xcode 7. So where can I find it in xcode 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **To change the locking level of a view**
>
> 1. In Interface Builder, select the view you want to lock.
> 2. In the  Identity inspector (under the Document section), choose a locking level from the Lock pop-up menu.
>
> **To change the locking level of the nib file**
>
> 1. In project navigator, select a .storyboard or .xib file.
> 2. Choose a locking level from the Editor > Localization Locking menu.

[See Locking Views Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html)